# How to upload a dataframe to Google Cloud Storage(bucket) on Python 3?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to create a Cloud Function (which shall be executed daily at 01:00).
The function should

1. generate a dataframe
2. [export as dataframe.csv]  <---- not sure if required
3. push the dataframe(or .csv) to a bucket

.....

- Question1: Is it possible to push a dataframe to a bucket?
- Question2: How can I create a .csv file within the CloudFunction(CF), that it can be pushed to a bucket?

Updated code now: (still giving error)

```
def push_cars( data ):    ##  <<----- not sure how many paramter &why??

    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    from datetime import datetime

    from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob
    from google.cloud import storage
    #import csv               # <<--- not sure if required???


    cars_dict = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

    cars = pd.DataFrame(cars_dict, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
    name = "cars_" + timestamp + ".csv"

    cars.to_csv(  "/tmp/test.csv" ,index=False)
    with open('/tmp/test.csv', "w") as csv: 
      csv.write(name) 

    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "My-project.json"

    target_bucket = 'cars:python_gogo'


    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket         = storage_client.get_bucket(  target_bucket )
    data           = bucket        .blob(        name_output   )
```

For replication on the cloud, you need to create a requirements.txt with following content:

```
requests
pandas
google-cloud-storage
datetime
```

In the cloud shell, i am using following to deploy this CF:
gcloud functions deploy push_cars--entry-point=push_cars--runtime=python37 --memory=1024MB --region=us-east1 --allow-unauthenticated --trigger-http

Comment: You can't just push a dataframe. Gotta serialize it first.

Comment: Is there a work-around? Can I export the dataframe as .csv. And push this .csv to the bucket?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `df.to_csv('file path')` to directly save the CSV in the cloud storage bucket. Put your gcs bucket route in place of the file path.

For example - `df.to_csv('gs://bucketname/filename.csv')`

Comment: This is a nice option if you have installed `gcsfs` along with` fsspec` . These two need to be correctly installed together .

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

The dataframe cannot be written directly to Cloud Storage, it is needed to be a file( can be the .csv you mentioned) and then you can write the file to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
This means that Step 2 is required.

Question 2:

Once you have `dataframe.csv` saved in `/tmp` you can transfer it to the Google Cloud Storage buket.

The code implementing both things will be something like this:

```
def push_cars( data, context ):

    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    from datetime import datetime

    from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob
    from google.cloud import storage


    cars_dict = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

    cars = pd.DataFrame(cars_dict, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
    name = "cars_" + timestamp + ".csv"

    cars.to_csv(  cars ,index=False)
    with open('/tmp/test.csv', "w") as csv: 
      csv.write(cars) 

    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "My-project.json"

    target_bucket = 'sp500_python_gogo'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket         = storage_client.get_bucket(  target_bucket )
    with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as file_obj:
      upload_blob(target_bucket, file_obj, name)
```

Comment: just tried that approach, and still not work.
1. I am not sure, if it is possible to save a .csv file in this environment. Got also error code: "Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'test.csv'"

2. I am not sure if it is required to import csv package

Comment: 3. I am not sure, if using the gcloud function for the deployment is correct: "gcloud functions deploy [name]--entry-point=[name]--runtime=python37 --memory=1024MB --region=us-east1 --allow-unauthenticated --trigger-http"
4. I am not sure, how many parameter this function really needs! def push_cars( data)?